# Can i use the download mode in lg g3 without turning on usb debugging

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking

I recently bricked my lg g3 d855 european. But still i can get it into download mode. When i connect it to a pc, it does not get recognized. I tried the kdz method to unbrick it but it gets stuck at 60% in lg flash tool. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; Download Mode has nothing at all to do with USB Debugging (which is for ADB).

You should ensure you have [the correct drivers](http://tool.lime.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=UW00120120425) installed and may want to try a different USB port and/or cable.